# Display three listings side-by-side (consider that the page size might change)

Tags: listings, multicol, textwidth

## The context

I want to display 3 listings side-by-side. I've managed to display 2 listings side-by-side with the following minimal working example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings, lipsum}
\usepackage[a5paper, showframe]{geometry}

\lstset{
  basicstyle = \ttfamily\tiny,
  frame = single
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
print("1")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
print("2")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%

\lipsum[2][1-2]
\end{document}
```

Since I've used the `\hfill` command, if the page size were to change, each listing would occupy, approximately, half of the page (see images below)

**A2 paper**

[image]

**A4 paper**

[image]

**A6 paper**

[image]

## The problem

I've already managed to display 3 listings side-by-side. However, there are minor details which I would like to fix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings, lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}

\lstset{
  basicstyle = \ttfamily\tiny,
  frame = single
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
print("3")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.4cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
print("4")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.4cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.33\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
print("5")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%

\lipsum[2][1-2]
\end{document}
```

Since I've used the `\hspace` command to hard code the spacing between the listings, if the page size were to change, all listings together wouldn't occupy the whole width in such a way  that they don't surpass the text width (see images below).

**A2 paper**

[image]

**A4 paper**

[image]

**A6 paper**

[image]

In this example, you can note why hard coding make listings not to be properly displayed within the column boundaries.

## The question

How can I display 3 listings side-by-side so that the following requirements are met

1. The spacing between them is not hard coded.
2. If the page size changed, they together must occupy the whole width without exaggeratedly surpassing the text width.

## Additional context

I know changing the page size is not commonly performed. For this reason, hard coding the sizes might be correct but I still want to find a way to specify the width in terms of proportions instead of fixed sizes ([hard coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895789/what-does-hard-coded-mean)).

Note that I've hard coded a width in the 2 columns example (i.e. `.48`). Ideally, even that size must not be hard coded. The reason I did this was because I didn't find another way to get that behavior.

Comment: What about `\hfill` instead of `\hspace{0.4cm}`? You already seem to have used that in the first example. Why not also in the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `\xleftmargin` and `\xrightmargin` equal to `\framesep`, they will fit to the linewidth. and with `paracol`, you can set the value of `\columnsep` to control the sep between the code boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings, lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{calc}

\lstset{
  basicstyle = \ttfamily\tiny,
  frame = single,
  xleftmargin=3pt,
  xrightmargin=3pt,
  framesep = 3pt,
}

\newcommand{\test}{
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]

\begin{paracol}{3}
\begin{lstlisting}
print("3")
\end{lstlisting}

\switchcolumn
\begin{lstlisting}
print("4")
\end{lstlisting}

\switchcolumn
\begin{lstlisting}
print("5")
\end{lstlisting}
\switchcolumn
\end{paracol}

\lipsum[2][1-2]

\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
\begin{paracol}{3}
\begin{lstlisting}
print("3")
\end{lstlisting}

\switchcolumn
\begin{lstlisting}
print("4")
\end{lstlisting}

\switchcolumn
\begin{lstlisting}
print("5")
\end{lstlisting}
\switchcolumn
\end{paracol}

\lipsum[3][1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To ensure the boxes don't exceed the textwidth, you will also have to take into account the width of the frame, not only the value of framesep.

Comment: @leandriis It seems that there is no such option to control the width of the frame directly, instead I guess the width of the frame = `linewidth + 2*framesep + framxleftmargin + framxrightmargin`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the following is closer to the desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings, lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}

\newlength{\mymargincorrection}
\setlength{\mymargincorrection}{3.4pt}
\lstset{
  basicstyle = \ttfamily\tiny,
  frame = single, 
    xleftmargin=\mymargincorrection,
    xrightmargin=\mymargincorrection,
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
print("3")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
print("4")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.33\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
print("5")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\mymargincorrection}%

\lipsum[2][1-2]
\end{document}
```

A2:

[image]

A4:

[image]

A6:

[image]